# What is the name of the javascript "namespace" pattern, that Typescript compiles to?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, typescript

By default, this Typescript code

```
module Demo {
    export class HelloWorld {
        sayHello() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

compiles to the following Javascript

```
var Demo;
(function (Demo) {
    var HelloWorld = (function () {
        function HelloWorld() {
        }
        HelloWorld.prototype.sayHello = function () {
            return "Hello World";
        };
        return HelloWorld;
    })();
    Demo.HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
})(Demo || (Demo = {}));
```

Is there a name for this Javascript namespace pattern and is it feasible to use it when writing pure Javascript (for example are there any better solutions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very much so. The main reason is that it prevents name collision. e.g. consider the following javascript code:

```
function format(str){
    // some dummy code 
    return str + " formatted";
}

function format(num){
    // some dummy code
    return num.toPrecision(10);
}

// beyond this point you cannot access format("str") version since it was replaced by format(number)
```

With typescript internal modules, you could just do:

```
module stringUtils {
    export function format(str:string){
        // some dummy code 
        return str + " formatted";
    }
}

module numberUtils{
    export function format(num:number){
        // some dummy code
        return num.toPrecision(10);
    }
}

stringUtils.format('some string');
numberUtils.format(123);
```

Additionally it allows you to prevent global namespace pollution when you want private functions local to your code, e.g consider this case:

```
module Utils{
    // Cache and compiled the regex
    // This regext is not very useful outside this module
    var trimRegex = RegExp("^\s+|\s+$"); 

    // This function is useful so we export it
    export function trim(str:string) {
      return str.replace(trimRegex,'');
    }
}

// You cannot use trimRegex now. 
// Your namespace is clean 
// you can use Utils.trim though :)
```

And as [Steve Fenton mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356683/what-is-the-name-of-the-javascript-namespace-pattern-that-typescript-compiles/18357326#comment26950331_18357326), this pattern is actively used in JavaScript as well (called self executing anonymous function).

Comment: +1 - the JavaScript name for this pattern is "self-executing anonymous functions", the part of this code that belongs to the pattern is... `(function () { })();`.